# MVC4. Setting default and success value of ValidationMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using this line to represent my models validation message:

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Email, "")

It workds in the manner that when the attribute isn't valid, it's set to the proper error message.
I want to extend this so it first shows a default message, then a success message if the attribute "Email" is valid.

So..

Default: Please enter your email here.
!Valid: The email is not valid (working)
Valid: Thanks, you'll receive an email after completing the registration.

Is there any way to add default & successful messages?

Comment: You would think it would come with this functionality out of the box.  But it does not.  You can create a helper function that will use jquery to validate the values.

Comment: Thanks, it's a pity that they haven't implemented support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery, on mail input [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) trigger the validation and change the message.